# Utilizing Kafka Streams to consume a topic for join, followed by new record production into the same topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using a LEFT JOIN to enrich my main event stream. However, at the end of the stream, I want to create an event in the topic I used for the LEFT JOIN on the right side. When I attempted to run this code, after consuming the first record, I encountered a NullPointerException loop in thread. It appears that after the first record is created for the Topics.NOTIFICATION, the state of the KTable is updated and the stream is triggered again from the start(?), which was not what I expected.

Is my topology valid at all? Or is what I'm trying to accomplish here considered an antipattern and should be approached differently? Unfortunately, I cannot provide any specific exception because it seems like a bug or a corner case in the usage of Kafka streams. I would expect that if the topology were invalid, it would be thrown during its build process.

Here's the code snippet:

```
KTable<Key, Notification> notificationKTable = builder.table(Topics.NOTIFICATION, Consumed.with(Key.serde(), Notification.serdes));

builder.table(Topics.USER_STATE, Consumed.with(Key.serde(), UserState.serde()))
        .leftJoin(
                notificationKTable,
                joinNotification(),
                Materialized.with(Key.serde()), UserState.serde())
        .filter(UserState::needToNotify)
        .toStream()
        .map(...)
        .to(Topics.NOTIFICATION, Produced.with(Key.serde(), Notification.serdes))
```